# Android: refresh the map and clear all itemizedoverlay

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-mapview

I'm trying to remove all my itemizedoverlay from my map, but I can't and I don't know why.
I've read many tutorials and in all of them there is the following solution:

```
        itemizedoverlay.clear();            
        mMapView.invalidate();
```

But it doesn't work!

I'm trying to do this in an AsyncTask in which first of all I do the (in the onPreExecute() ):

```
        itemizedoverlay.clear();            
        mMapView.invalidate();
```

then I get all my geopoint from my server, I create a list of myitemizedoverlay object (in the doInBackground() ) and I put them in the map like this (in the onPostExecute() ):

```
            for (int i = 0; i < myListOfOverlayItem.size(); i++) {
                itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(myListOfOverlayItem.get(i));
            }
            overlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
```

Why my code doesn't update my map? :-/

This is the code of the clear:

```
public void clear(){
    this.m_overlays.clear();
    setLastFocusedIndex(-1); 
    populate();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try the follow this pattern: in `doInBackground()` create the overlay, in `onPostExecute()` execute `clear()`, then add the overlay, then call `invalidate`. Check the documentation if `onPreExecute()` runs on the **UI thread** or on a **background thread**. I assume it is not safe to **invalidate a map view** if it runs on a background thread.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
mMapView.getOverlays().clear();
```

More info/javadocs here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView

Comment: If I use your method, the map refresh erase myLocationOverlay and not the other itemizedoverlay. =(

Comment: yea...this is going to happen.  hold a reference to your location overlay and in your clear method add it again after the getOverlays().clear()  call

Comment: Yea...you are going to need to add your locationoverlay on clear() if you want it to stay on the screen.  There isnt any way around it.  However adding it should be really fast and unnoticable. Best of luck macho! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you do overlays.clear() in the beginning of your procedure and mMapView.invalidate() at the end?

Comment: I launch the 2 functions at the start of the procedure. In the onPreExecute() of the async task.

Comment: I noticed that you do itemizedoverlay.clear instead of overlays.clear and should not mMapView.invalidate be done _after_ you add new stuff to overlays? Well, I am struggling with maps myself, so my comments may not be very useful :)